# EspoCRM Report an error Possible problem: disabled URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-10, espocrm

My friend, I tried to install EspoCRM on windows 2019, but a fatal problem occurred, which prevented me from installing it normally. Can you help me solve it, my friend?
The following is the error message.

API Error: EspoCRM API is unavailable.
Possible problem: disabled "URL Rewrite". Please check and enable "URL Rewrite" Module in IIS server

Comment: I have installed URL rewriting, but it cannot solve the problem.

Comment: what is the php server you are using?

Comment: My friend ，I use windows server 2019 iis10

Comment: Restart your computer and try again. If you still can’t solve the problem, you can try to create a rule in url rewrite, such as redirect http to https, etc., to see if it works.